# django UniqueConstraint violation_error_message message not handled

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have this model:

```
class DataMapping(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(LocationDepartment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    catagory = models.ForeignKey(CompanyCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.ForeignKey(ReasonForProcessing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
            constraints = [
                UniqueConstraint(
                    name='unique_data_map', 
                    fields=['company', 'location', 'department', 'catagory', 'reason'],
                    condition=Q(location__isnull=False),
                    violation_error_message="This data map has already been added.",
                ),
                UniqueConstraint(
                    name='unique_data_map_both_none_dep_none', 
                    fields=['company', 'location', 'catagory', 'reason'],
                    condition=Q(department__isnull=True),
                    violation_error_message="This data map has already been added."
                ),
                UniqueConstraint(
                    name='unique_data_map_both_none', 
                    fields=['company', 'catagory', 'reason'],
                    condition=Q(location__isnull=True) & Q(department__isnull=True),
                    violation_error_message="This data map has already been added."
                )
    ]
```

with a basic modelform

```
class DataMapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataMapping
        fields = (
            'location',
            'department',
            'catagory',
            'reason',
    )
    widgets = {
        'company': forms.HiddenInput()
    }
```

and a view of:

```
def data_mapping_new(request):
    company = get_current_logged_in_company(request)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataMapForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            catagory = form.save(commit=False)
            catagory.company = company
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
```

I have a similar setup on a different model that works fine, but this one just raises an error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_data_map_both_none"`

Should it not check the constraint at the first `if form.is_valid():`

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
I used a similar pattern for a model somewhere else and it works fine there, with the only difference there being that the condition is on a char field and not a foreign key as in this model. `condition=Q(email__isnull=False) & Q(email__gt='')`.  Maybe my issue is in how I set up the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of "when in doubt cout", I noticed that model forms only check constraints that include all the fields that the form includes.  In my case the model included

```
'location',
'department',
'catagory',
'reason',
```

but the constraint included `company`.  I did not add company here as it is not something the user sets in the form, but it is a hidden field.  Point is that the constraint did not trigger as the constraint includes company.  Adding company to the fields list in the model form resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `form.save(commit=False)` line, which does not include all the fields necessary to satisfy the unique constraints specified in the model's `Meta` class. When you call `form.save(commit=False)`, you are creating a new instance of the `DataMapping` model that has not yet been saved to the database. Then you are assigning the company field to the current company, but you are not assigning values to the other fields that are part of the unique constraint.

Try to add those fields before calling `form.save()` like so:

```py
def data_mapping_new(request):
    company = get_current_logged_in_company(request)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataMapForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data_mapping = form.save(commit=False)
            data_mapping.company = company
            data_mapping.location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            data_mapping.department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            data_mapping.catagory = form.cleaned_data['catagory']
            data_mapping.reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']

            
            data_mapping.save()

    # ...
```

The above solution should work but additionally I'd recommend you to see [`Using request.POST or None`](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-request-post-or-none.html) antipattern made by Sir [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem).

Comment: Thanks for the antipattern.  Good tip.  Unfortunately the rest of your solution does not work.  Still getting the same error where the postgress tries to commit with unique constraints raising the error.

Comment: @ChristoLabuschagne I'd see it and reply to you later :)